# Number of expected turns to get $k$ distinct numbers

Tags: probability, coupon-collector-problem

We have a random number generator, which generates **random numbers from $1$ to $N$**. Each number has an equal probability of occurring **(equiprobable)**.
Find the expected number of turns to get **$k$ distinct** numbers from the random number generator.

.

PS: This question came in the placement test of some company, and I was unable to solve it. Moreover, I couldn't find any good theorem or resource on the internet for this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you do any part of it? Do you understand what "expected number" means?

Comment: No, I am new to probability.

Comment: This is a generalization of the [coupon collector problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon+collector), about which you can find many posts here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a stage in this process where exactly $i$ distinct numbers have already been seen $(0 \le i \lt N).$  "Equiprobable" means that *on average,* out of every $N$ times this stage is reached, in $i$ cases the next number drawn will be among those seen and in the remaining $j=N-i$ cases it will be a new number.  Thus, *the expected number of draws to see a new number, given $j$ distinct numbers remain to be seen, must be $N/j.$*  (This intuitive result is made rigorous by invoking the Geometric distribution: see [the Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).)

The expected number of draws to reach $k$ distinct numbers ($k=1, 2, \ldots, N$) is the sum of these values, starting at $j=N$ (no numbers drawn yet) going down to (and including) $j=N-(k-1):$

> $$E[\text{number of draws to reach } k]=\sum_{j=N-(k-1)}^N \frac{N}{j} = N(H_N - H_{N-k})$$

where $$H_N = \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{j}$$ is the [$N^\text{th}$ harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).  (Of course $H_0=0.$)

A special case is $k=N,$ the number of draws expected to collect all $N$ numbers (the [coupon-collector](/questions/tagged/coupon-collector) problem), equal to $NH_N.$

Here is a plot of the results for a simulation of length 5000.  The heights of the bars are the average numbers of turns observed in the simulation.  The red curve is the graph of $N(H_N-H_{N-K}).$  You can see how the time needed to observe a new number increases especially sharply at the very end.  This is characteristic of the situation for all $N.$

[image: Figure]

The agreement between the simulation and the theoretical result is excellent. If you wish to explore this further, here is the `R` code.

```R
#
# Simulate the process directly by successive sampling -- no shortcuts.
# Implicitly, at step `i+1` all the previous numbers are re-indexed from `1`
# through `i` so that the test of a new number is fast: it must exceed `i`.
# The output is an array of times at which each new number was observed.
#
collect <- function(N) {
  cumsum(sapply(1:N-1, function(i) {
    count <- 0
    repeat{
      count <- count+1 
      if(sample.int(N, 1) > i) break
    } 
    count
  }))
}
#
# Harmonic numbers.  See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html
#
H <- function(N) 0.577215664901532861 + digamma(N+1)
#
# Simulation.
#
N <- 30
x <- replicate(5e3, collect(N))
#
# Plotting.
#
plot(rowMeans(x), type="h", lwd=2, ylab="Expectation", xlab=expression(k),
     main=paste("Expected Turns for N =", N))          # The results
curve(N * (H(N) - H(N-x)), add=TRUE, col="Red", lwd=2) # Theoretical values
```